# No sound on Gateway NE56R 64-Bit

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound

I have a Gateway NE56R and sometimes the sound just doesn't work when I start up the computer. Also, when I first turn on my computer and Ubuntu begins to boot, I get messages saying stuff. I think I just need to reinstall my drivers. How can I install drivers for my sound and how can I make sure that driver is enabled? I don't want to install a sound driver just to notice that my sound is using a different driver on my computer. I have noticed that the sound does work just fine before I log in. Also, on startup of my computer, at the black boot screen, I get a few errors:

```
drm module has bad taint, not creating trace events
i915 module has bad taint, not creating trace events
snd_hda_controller module has bad taint, not creating trace events
snd_hda_codec module has bad taint, not creating trace events
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages are not showing a real problem, only limited  log from soundcard  .
As you have sound before login, then Alsa driver layer is ok. So the problem is with pulseaudio configuration in your session. Install pavucontrol (pulse audio volume control) and when sound is not ok , look in output device tab if  correct sound output is selected (en general you don't want  HDMI sound output). Look also "configuration" tab  and test other profile.
If it stills not good,  when sound stops, copy and run this in a terminal:

`killall -9 pulseaudio`

Close and reopen audio apps and test.
If not good, copy and run that commands in a terminal:
`killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ~/.config/pulse`
and reboot

Comment: How do I get rid of the "limited log from soundcard" message?

Comment: You can only wait  kernel update, or it could be that intel driver as non-gpl parts,  (look http://www.tux.org/lkml/#export-tainted  ), but if sound is ok, this is not a problem as this message is informative only.

Comment: A new kernel update came out today and it does make it all disappear! Hooray!